# The behavior for Date objects stored in Firestore is going to change and your app may break

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am stuck at this point while working on VueJs as i want to log the data from firebase .
I changed the code according to the suggestions on the console but nothing is working . I am using Vue Cli 3 and firebase 5.5.9 .

```
<script>
import db from './firebaseInit'
export default {
name: 'dashboard',
    data(){
        return{
            employees: []
        }
    },
    created(){
        db.collection('employees').get().then
        (querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                console.log(doc.data())
                const data = {

                }
            })
        })
    }
}
</script>
```

This is my firebaseInit.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase'

import 'firebase/firestore'
import firebaseConfig from './firebaseConfig'
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

// const firestore = firebase.firestore();
// const settings = {timestampsInSnapshots: true};
// firestore.settings(settings);
export default firebaseApp.firestore()
```

Answer (score 1):

As shown in both the error message and [this github issue](https://github.com/gdg-tangier/vue-firestore/issues/11), you need to initialize the `firestore` object with an instruction on how to store date/timestamp fields.

So:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'

import 'firebase/firestore'
import firebaseConfig from './firebaseConfig'
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

const firestore = firebase.firestore();
const settings = {timestampsInSnapshots: true};
const api = firestore.settings(settings);
export default api;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer . It worked for me . But another thing is that it is not logging the doc.data() in the console . I restarted the development server but nothing happens .

Comment: That seems unrelated to the warning message that you started your post with. The first step to troubleshooting would be to put a breakpoint on `querySnapshot.forEach(...` and see if that fires.

Answer (score 0):

```
import firebase from "firebase";
import "firebase/firestore";
import firebaseConfig from "./firabaseConfig.js";

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);    
firebaseApp.firestore().settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });

export default firebaseApp.firestore();
```

it works for me. you can give it a try. :)

Comment: It is working . But another thing is that it is not logging the doc.data() in the console . I restarted the development server but nothing happens

Comment: did it log doc.data() in the console before? can you please attach the code by how you logged data in the console?

Comment: yes you can see the code in my question . In which i log the data.doc() in created method .